Send Survey recap email to users (SwiftSMTP)
I have a Swiftui view in my app that is a a simple survey about the app.
The survey is made of a few questions and I ask the user to put their email at the end.
When the user submit the hit button, I would like the app to send a recap email to the user (and to me). Since I have a domain and an email, I thought it would be smart to solve it directly in swiftui.

I am trying to use SwiftSMTP : https://swiftpackageindex.com/Kitura/Swift-SMTP

I have an OVH domain, so I filled with infos found here, https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/en-mx-plan-mail-macos-configuration?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0052090

I tried to test the SMTP server on this : https://mailmeteor.com/tools/smtp-test, seems to work fine.

I tried using both smtp.mail.ovh.net or ssl0.ovh.net and both 587 and 465 as ports

This always return an authentification error for some reasons.



error in connection_block_invoke_2: Connection invalid
Error sending email: The preferred authorization methods could not be found on ssl0.ovh.net, or your server is sending back a STARTTLS command and requires a connection upgrade.
Admin email sending failed

Is there a better / easier way of doing this? Is it not possible to do something like this for privacy reasons ?
Thanks a lot for the help.
Code looks like this :
// MODULE TO SEND EMAIL
func sendRecapEmail(to recipientEmail: String, surveyData: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let smtp = SMTP(
        hostname: "ssl0.ovh.net",
        email: "XXXX@XXXXX.eu",
        password: "XXXXX",
        port: 465, 
        tlsMode: .normal
    )
    
    let sender = Mail.User(name: "XXXX@XXXXX.eu", email: "XXXX@XXXXX.eu")
    let recipient = Mail.User(email: recipientEmail)
    
    let surveyRecap = surveyData.map { "\($0.key): \($0.value)" }.joined(separator: "\n")
    let mail = Mail(
        from: sender,
        to: [recipient],
        subject: "Survey replies overview",
        text: "Thank you \n\nHere is a recap of what you submitted:\n\(surveyRecap)"
    )
    
    smtp.send(mail) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error sending email: \(error)")
            completion(false)
        } else {
            print("Recap email sent successfully!")
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}

and then I submit like that :
// SUBMIT FUNCTION
func handleSurveySubmission(
    surveyData: [String: Any],
    recipientEmail: String,
    completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void
) {
    let adminEmail = "XXXX@XXXXX.eu" 
    
    // Send email to the admin
    sendRecapEmail(to: adminEmail, surveyData: surveyData) { adminSuccess in
        if !adminSuccess {
            print("Admin email sending failed")
            completion(false)
            return
        }
        
        // If admin email succeeds, send confirmation email to the user
        sendRecapEmail(to: recipientEmail, surveyData: surveyData) { userSuccess in
            if !userSuccess {
                print("User email sending failed")
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            
            // If both emails succeed
            print("Both emails sent successfully!")
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}


There is no SwiftUI here

Swift - corrected.

Even if you could get it to work, embedding credentials in your app is not secure. I would suggest you look at a service, such as Twilio Sendgrid. Alternatively, do you need to send an email? Could you just store the responses in some data store, such as FireStore?
